# Detach SQL DB accessed in multiple processes

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a set of programs (consider parent and child processes) that access the same SQL database.  It is attached and detached during the course of the program(s).  I am having trouble only when I try and detach it when both processes have accessed it.  The connections are all closed, but if I try to execute the sp_detach stored procedure, I get an error message that it is in use and cannot be detached.  Is there something about the multi-process access that I need to address?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing specific about multi-process access providing that all connections are closed. In your case, I suspect that one of the connections is not truly closed, you just think it is.

Before calling sp_detach, run the following code:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

I always think this is best practise for automated procedures of this nature in the spirit of defensive coding. (Not that I would normaly consider a database detach in the middle of an automated process best practise)

Comment: This seems to be the main answer I find in detach problem scenarios.  I did manage to figure out that if I detach the database in the first process before the second process accesses it, I have no issues.  While this is hardly a good solution (I am in total agreement on the detach/best practice comment) it at least helped steer me.  I think I will take your advice on the single user mode.

One question, though.  Does the set multi user command have to ever be set again later?

Comment: No, not in your scenario. When you re-attach, it will be in multi user mode